# shared libraries of dig and nslookup

Tags: linux, networking, nslookup, dig

I am using `centos 6.4`. While doing dig or nslookup, I got below error

## **dig google.com**

```
dig: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

here is **my ldd of dig**

```
'# ldd /usr/bin/dig 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff5e674000)
    liblwres.so.80 => /usr/lib64/liblwres.so.80 (0x00007f73d5c1c000)
    libdns.so.81 => /usr/lib64/libdns.so.81 (0x00007f73d5883000)
    libbind9.so.80 => /usr/lib64/libbind9.so.80 (0x00007f73d5676000)
    libisccfg.so.82 => /usr/lib64/libisccfg.so.82 (0x00007f73d5454000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f73d5210000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f73d4e75000)
    libisccc.so.80 => /usr/lib64/libisccc.so.80 (0x00007f73d4c6d000) '
    ....
```

Do you know how can I fix this error?

Please help,

Thanks,
SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a soft link

> ln -s /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 /lib

Let us know if that helped you.

Or you can remove and install again using yum. Normally library files places to its apt position when installs using yum.

> yum remove dns-utils
>
> yum install dns-utils

You can enable epel repositories in case you need it [epel](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x)

Comment: It still not help, I still getting same error :( Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying

> ldd /usr/bin/dig

Are you able to find a line like

> libcrypto.so.4 => not found

If so Try

> locate libcrypto.so.4

Suppose you can locate the file at /path/to/file/libcrypto.so.4

then try the command

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/file"

Then try command dig. It should be fine. Other wise you need to search for the package that provides the libcrypto.so.4 library

Comment: When doing ldd /usr/bin/dig, there is no "libcrypto.so.4 => not found" But I found only "libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10" I try to find the package for install too. But can't found yet