# dig: error while loading shared libraries: libdns.so.162: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, https, server, dns, dig

Hello I'm on my server and i try to enable https, but i have this error

```
dig: error while loading shared libraries: libdns.so.162: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I 've find this similar question but I don't reach to solve my problem.

[shared libraries of dig and nslookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360593/shared-libraries-of-dig-and-nslookup#17365651)

if i type

```
ldd /usr/bin/dig
```

I see

```
libdns.so.1100 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdns.so.1100
```

but not

```
libdns.so.162
```

Can someone help me to solve this my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. You might want to try [superuser] instead. Also you forgot to mention your linux distribution. In all cases you shouldn't install anything like this by hand, just use your OS package system and things should work. Otherwise you will have to describe what you did to your system to arrive at this stage.