# Rocket Chat cannot enable SSL using Caddy: libdns.so.162 not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, rocket.chat, caddy

I installed [rocket chat](https://rocket.chat/) using snap, following the documentation [here](https://docs.rocket.chat/installation/snaps).

Now I am trying to enable SSL following the documentation: [Auto SSL with Snaps](https://docs.rocket.chat/installation/snaps/autossl). However, the following error shows up:

```
$ sudo snap set rocketchat-server https=enable
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "rocketchat-server" snap (run hook "configure": 
-----
dig: error while loading shared libraries: libdns.so.162: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: Can't resove DNS query for <my_domain_name>, check your DNS configuration, disabling https ...
-----)
```

Checking what `ldd` has to say for `dig`, I found few other libs are also not found:

```
$ ldd /snap/rocketchat-server/current/usr/bin/dig 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffff98afc000)
    libdns.so.162 => not found
    liblwres.so.141 => not found
    libbind9.so.140 => not found
    libisccfg.so.140 => not found
    libisc.so.160 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000ffff98a71000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffff98900000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffff98acc000)
```

So, checked if `libdns.so` exists at all.

```
$ locate libdns.so
/snap/rocketchat-server/1437/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdns.so.162
/snap/rocketchat-server/1437/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdns.so.162.1.3
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdns.so.1601
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdns.so.1601.0.0
```

It appears that the concerned library exists under snap.

Is there a way to resolve this and make caddy/https work?

---

System:

- Raspberry Pi 4 (aarch64)
- Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1022-raspi
- Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS

---

Similar issues:

- [dig: error while loading shared libraries: libdns.so.162: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675537/dig-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libdns-so-162-cannot-open-shared-obj)
- [shared libraries of dig and nslookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360593/shared-libraries-of-dig-and-nslookup)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a soft-link to library in your file system

```
ln -s /snap/rocketchat-server/1437/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdns.so.162 /lib
```

Or install dns-utils which should add missing lib to your system.